# Using a Viewbox, can I scale a Webview without actually scaling the contents?

Tags: c#, webview, windows-store-apps

I'm experimenting with the Webview control in a Windows Store Application, and I wanted it to scale with all resolutions so I placed the control in a Viewbox.

It scales fine, and fits with any resolution which is great, however the content inside the control scales too, and I was wondering if there was a way to just scale the Webview's size without actually making the content inside any bigger.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did u get any solution??

Answer (score 2):

You can use a scale factor. We are doing this to force 1920x1080 content into a WebView. We calculate our scale factor based on the native resolution divided by the desired resolution.

From what I can tell 1366x768 is the Surface Pro's resolution for WinRT apps. With this I got a scale factor of 0.71 (1366/1920).

This is working for us on Windows 8.1

```
<WebView>
    <WebView.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleY="0.71" ScaleX="0.71"/>
    </WebView.RenderTransform>
</WebView>
```